# выравнивание блока по контенту

Tags: html, css

в `$chose_address.` падают адреса из бд и выглядят так `<span class="chose_delivery_address">...</span>`. Вопрос в том как сделать ширину `span`ов по длине текста который будет туда помещен и отдалить каждыый спан друг от друга ( падинги и марджины игнорит)

HTML

```
 <div id="chose_delivery_address_block">
                <div id="chose_delivery_address_number">'.$personal_data_form['personal_data_form']['delivery_address'].'</div>
                <img  id ="delivery_change_arrow" src="'.IMAGE.'menu/bt_arrow.png" alt=""> 
                <div id="hidden_chose_address">

                    '.$chose_address.'

                </div>  
            </div>
```

css

```
#chose_delivery_address_number{
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:15px; 
    display:inline-block; 
}

#chose_delivery_address_block{
    width:150px;
    position: relative;
}

#hidden_chose_address{
    display:inline-table;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    z-index:20;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #afafaf;
    border-right: 1px solid #afafaf;
    border-left: 1px solid #afafaf;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;   
    max-width: 803px;
    width:803px;    
}
```

Comment: спаны и так имеют ширину по ширине контента, так как являются inline - элементами, а так же из-за этого между ними промежуток в один пробел. Если вы не меняли стили именно для спанов то все должно работать так как вы и хотите

Comment: действительно, а как тогда подтянуть контейнер спанов по ихней ширине

Comment: сделайте пример который можно запустить и увидеть результат аналогичный вашему, например тут в snippet(кнопка `{}` в редакторе) или на jsfiddle, или Plunkr

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/prduw43j/4/ вроде бы так

Comment: ну или хотя бы прикрутить скролл, если текст спана лезет в 2 ряда

Comment: какой стиль у `.chose_delivery_address`?